# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen failed: library "libavutil.so" not found

Tags: android, libav

Facing a lot of crashes in the Android Devices with the above error

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen failed: library
> "libavutil.so" not found

```java
init {
    try{
        System.loadLibrary("avutil")
        System.loadLibrary("avcodec")
        System.loadLibrary("avformat")
        System.loadLibrary("swscale")
        System.loadLibrary("avfilter")
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Log.i("error","${e.message}")
    }
}
```

In app/build.gradle

```
ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

Comment: You could try ReLinker library if you are sure that your `libavutil.so` is indeed shipped in the app but still causes loading issues.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.arthenica/mobile-ffmpeg-full/4.4 for my video editing app.

Comment: What device(s) especially the used CPU architecture? How do you install your app on it (side-loading, Play Store, ..)? If you do side-loading have you analyzed the generated APK file if it contains the library for the used CPU architecture?

Comment: 65% --> Vivo, 
Infinix Smart 7 HD4%
Oppo
3%
Oppo
2%
Symphony - WindRiver
1%
Samsung

Comment: I have analysed the apk, it has the 64-bit architecture and able to see the libavuil.so in lib folder

Comment: Can I restrict this for oppo models alone